# Jira Migration Issue

Tags: jira

We want to migrate Jira from one server to another server.

Currently we are at 6.4.3 Jira version and the one on which we want to migrate is 7.12.

We are facing the following issue.

> The xml data you are trying to import is too old to be upgraded by this version of Jira.

#### Jira Migration Error:

[image: Jira Migration Error]

Comment: According to the link (in your image), you must go from 6.4.X to 7.0.X and THEN go to 7.12.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the 7.12 upgrade notes: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftware/jira-software-7-12-x-upgrade-notes-955173978.html

Specifically, if you look near the very bottom of that page you will see:

> Earlier than 7.0  Consult the Migration hub. The Jira 7.0 release
>   introduced significant changes. You must first upgrade to Jira 7.0 (we
>   recommend the latest bugfix release, in this case 7.0.11) before
>   upgrading to later versions.

So you will need to do a two-step upgrade: 6.4.3 -> 7.0.11 then 7.0.11 -> 7.12.x